# What is the advantage of using FlatMap over Map while transforming a webclient response?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient, flatmap

I’m consuming a third-party REST API using webclient. I need to transform the response and return the result asynchronously without blocking.

My understanding is

flatMap is asynchronous and map is synchronous.

In the below code snippet, I have used flatMap in approach 1 and map in approach 2.

**Question 1:** Is the approach1 asynchronous?

**Question 2:** What is the advantage of asynchronous (flatMap over map) here? I am just fetching a field from the response and setting the field again in a different object and returning it.

```
@PostMapping(value = “/test”, produces = { “application/json” })
public ResponseEntity<Mono<MyResponse>> test(@RequestBody String input) {
Mono<ThirdPartyResponse> response = myutil.invokeWebClient(input);

//approach 1

final Mono<MyResponse> transformedResponse1 = response.flatMap(value -> {
    final MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
    myResponse.setAccountNumber(value.getRoot().getMsgOut().getAcctNbr());
    return Mono.just(myResponse);
});

//approach 2

final Mono<MyResponse> transformedResponse2 = response.map(value -> {
    final MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
    myResponse.setAccountNumber(value.getRoot().getMsgOut().getAcctNbr());
    return myResponse;
});
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(transformedResponse1);
}
```

Comment: In that example flatMap doesn't make any sense at all. Typical case for a map

Answer (score 0):

The main differences between map and flatmap:

1. map() applies a one-to-one transformation to stream elements, while flatMap() does one-to-many.
2. map() is synchronous, ensuring that all items are processed in the order that they are received. flatMap() can be asynchronous, which does not guarantee that the order of execution follows the order of invoking.

More info on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reactor-map-flatmap).

Comment: I already referred to that. Why order of execution matter here? Let's say a web client is returning an object with 2 fields (age and citizenship). My transformer needs both 2 fields to determine whether the person is eligible to vote or not. What is the use of asynchronous here? If the web client returns a list of numbers and I need to just multiply all the numbers by 2 then asynchronous makes sense but in my scenario what is the use of using Flatmap over map?

Comment: In this case, if you will always only "do one thing" for every request, I don't see any preferences of using flatMap over map. Be aware that due to the architecture of Spring WebFlux, none of the options are blocking. They both produce events that are picked up by the event loop without blocking the main thread.